# Diagonal Scaling of $ A \in {\mathbb{R}}^{2 \times 2} $ Positive Definite and Its Conditional Number

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given a Positive Definite Matrix $ A \in {\mathbb{R}}^{2 \times 2} $ given by:

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
{A}_{11} & {A}_{12} \\ 
{A}_{12} & {A}_{22}
\end{bmatrix} $$

And a Matrix $ B $ Given by:

\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{{A}_{11}}} & 0 \\ 
0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{{A}_{22}}}
\end{bmatrix}

Now, defining the Diagonal Scaling of $ A $ given by $ C = B A B $.
One could see the main diagonal elements of $ C $ are all $ 1 $.
Actually $ C $ is given by:

$$ C = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & \frac{{A}_{12}}{\sqrt{ {A}_{11} {A}_{22} }} \\ 
\frac{{A}_{12}}{\sqrt{ {A}_{11} {A}_{22} }} & 1
\end{bmatrix} $$

This scaling, intuitively, makes the Matrix closer to the identity Matrix (Smaller off diagonal values, 1 on the main diagonal) and hence improve the Condition Number.
Yet I couldn't prove it.

How could one prove $ \kappa \left( C \right) = \kappa \left( B A B \right) \leq \kappa \left( A \right) $?

Comment: It is notable that we can explicitly calculate the eigenvalues of $C$ as
$$
\lambda = 1 \pm \frac{A_{12}}{\sqrt{A_{11}A_{12}}}
$$

Comment: Yes, I did it for both and tried to show the inequality of the division using Inequality of Arithmetic and Geometric Means and couldn't get to a satisfying result.

Comment: Moreover, $ C $ has always the same Eigen Vectors, built with $ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} $.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, Do you have nay suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition number and positive definiteness is independent of scaling the matrix by a positive scalar and the result is obviously true for diagonal matrices, so we may assume that
$$
A:=\pmatrix{\alpha&1\\1&\beta}, \quad \alpha,\beta>0, \quad 1<\alpha\beta
$$
(if the off-diagonal entry is negative, apply a similarity transformation with the diagonal matrix $\mathrm{diag}(1,-1)$).
Then
$$
\kappa(A)
=\frac{\alpha+\beta+\sqrt{(\alpha-\beta)^2+4}}{\alpha+\beta-\sqrt{(\alpha-\beta)^2+4}}
=\frac{1+\sqrt{\frac{(\alpha-\beta)^2+4}{(\alpha+\beta)^2}}}{1-\sqrt{\frac{(\alpha-\beta)^2+4}{(\alpha+\beta)^2}}}
$$
For the scaled matrix, we have
$$
\kappa(C)=\frac{1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{\alpha\beta}}}{1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{\alpha\beta}}}.
$$
Since $1<\alpha\beta$, you can show that both expressions are of the form
$\frac{1+\sqrt{t}}{1-\sqrt{t}}$ where $t\in[0,1)$. Since this function is increasing on this interval, we just need to verify that 
$$
\frac{1}{\alpha\beta}\leq \frac{(\alpha-\beta)^2+4}{(\alpha+\beta)^2}
$$
(again, using the assumptions on $\alpha$ and $\beta$).

---

By the way, your intuition might mislead you in the general case. Such a diagonal scaling might fail even for SPD matrices of size at least $3$.

Comment: Hi Pavel, I solved it in a different way (I had this brute force solution, thought could have something else).  Anyhow, thank you for your solution. I +1 and marked it. P.S. could you have a look on the answer I wrote? Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Since multiplying by a constant doesn't change the Condition Number one could make the choice of:

$$ A = \begin{bmatrix}
a & 1 \\ 
1 & b
\end{bmatrix} $$

Hence the matrix $ B $ becomes:

$$ B = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}} & 0 \\ 
0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{b}}
\end{bmatrix} $$

And the Matrix $ C $ becomes:

$$ C = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{ab}} \\ 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{ab}} & 1
\end{bmatrix} $$

Moreover, defining $ {\alpha}_{1} \geq {\alpha}_{2} $ are the Eigen Values of $ A $ and $ {\gamma}_{1} \geq {\gamma}_{2} $ are the Eigen Values of $ C $.

One should notice that $ \det \left( B \right) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{ab}} < 1 $ by the definition of $ C \succ 0 $ (By Quadratic Form of PD Matrix) or $ A \succ 0 $ which implies $ a b > 1 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{ab} < 1 $.
In addition since $ \kappa \left( A \right) = \frac{{\alpha}_{1}}{{\alpha}_{2}} $ and $ \det \left( A \right) = {\alpha}_{1} {\alpha}_{2} $ it follows that $ \det \left( A \right) \kappa \left( A \right) = {\alpha}_{1}^{2} $ and $ \det \left( A \right) {\det \left( B \right)}^{2} \kappa \left( C \right) = {\gamma}_{1}^{2} $.

Assuming the inequality holds:

$$ \kappa \left( C \right) \leq \kappa \left( A \right) \Rightarrow \det \left( A \right) \kappa \left( C \right) \leq \det \left( A \right) \kappa \left( A \right) $$

Since $ \det \left( A \right) > 0 $, now this implies:

$$ \frac{{\gamma}_{1}^{2}}{\det \left( B \right) \det \left( B \right)} \leq {\alpha}_{1}^{2} \Rightarrow {\gamma}_{1} \leq \det \left( B \right) {\alpha}_{1} $$

Namely, showing the above inequality of the Eigen Values is equivalent of proving the original inequality (Because all terms are positive).

One could see, using the [Characteristic Polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial) of the matrix $ A $ and $ C $ that $ {\alpha}_{1} = \frac{a + b}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{{\left( a - b \right)}^{2} + 4}}{2}, \; {\gamma}_{1} = 1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{ab}} $.

Working on the right hand of the inequality:

$$
\begin{align}
\det \left( B \right) {\alpha}_{1} & = \frac{1}{\sqrt{a b}} \left( \frac{a + b}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{{\left( a - b \right)}^{2} + 4}}{2} \right) \\
& = \frac{a + b}{2 \sqrt{a b}} + \sqrt{\frac{{\left( a - b \right)}^{2} + 4}{4 a b}} \\
& \geq 1 + \sqrt{\frac{{\left( a - b \right)}^{2} + 4}{4 a b}} \\ 
& \geq 1 + \sqrt{\frac{4}{4 a b}} \\
& = {\gamma}_{1}
\end{align}
$$

Where the first inequality comes from the [Inequality of Arithmetic and Geometric Means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means) and the second by removing a non negative term.

Comment: Just few comments: 1) Where did $\det(A)(B^2)\kappa(C)=\gamma_1^2$ come from (did you forget some $\det$ there)? 2) You cannot assume that what you want to show is true. You can show that what you want to show is equivalent to "something" and then to prove that "something" hereby proving the original statement. 3) I cannot see how (from what you wrote) we get $\frac{\gamma_1}{\gamma_2}\leq\frac{\alpha_1}{\alpha_2}$.

Comment: 1. I meant $ \det \left( A \right) \det \left( B \right) \det \left( B \right) $. 2. You can start at the last inequality, divide / multiply by positive numbers and get the original. 3. I showed the conditional number inequality -> Same as your inequality.